# Is it possible to guarantee the order in which @PostConstruct methods are invoked?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have a system which is using Spring for dependency injection.  I use annotation-based autowiring.  The beans are discovered by component scanning, i.e. my context XML contains this:

```XML
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

I have created a noddy example below to illustrate my problem.

There is a `Zoo` which is a container for `Animal` objects.  The developer of `Zoo` does not know which `Animal` objects will be contained whilst he is developing `Zoo`; the set of concrete `Animal` objects instantiated by Spring is known at compile-time, but there are various build profiles resulting in various sets of `Animal`s, and the code for `Zoo` must not change under these circumstances.

The purpose of `Zoo` is to allow other parts of the system (illustrated here as `ZooPatron`) to access the set of `Animal` objects at runtime, without needing to depend explicitly on certain `Animal`s.

Actually, the concrete `Animal` classes will all be contributed by various Maven artifacts.  I want to be able to assemble a distribution of my project by simply depending on the various artifacts containing these concrete `Animal`s, and have everything autowire correctly at compile-time.

I have attempted to solve this problem (unsuccessfully) by having the individual `Animal`s depend upon the `Zoo`, in order that they can call a registration method on the `Zoo` during `@PostConstruct`.  This avoids the `Zoo` depending explicitly on an explicit list of `Animal`s.

The problem with this approach is that the customers of `Zoo` wish to interact with it **only when all the `Animal`s have registered**.  There is a finite set of `Animal`s which is known at compile-time, and the registration all happens during the Spring wiring phase of my lifecycle, so a subscription model should be unneccesary (i.e. I don't wish to add `Animal`s to the `Zoo` at runtime).

Unfortunately, all the customers of `Zoo` simply depend upon `Zoo`.  This is exactly the same relationship which the `Animal`s have with `Zoo`.  Therefore, the `@PostConstruct` methods of the `Animal`s and `ZooPatron` are called in an arbitrary sequence.  This is illustrated with the example code below - at the time `@PostConstruct` is invoked on `ZooPatron`, no `Animal`s have registered, it is some milliseconds later when they all register.

So there are two types of dependency here, which I am struggling to express in Spring.  The customers of `Zoo` only want to use it once all the `Animal`s are in it.  (perhaps "Ark" would have been a better example...)

My question is basically: what is the best way to solve this problem?

```java
@Component
public class Zoo {

    private Set<Animal> animals = new HashSet<Animal>();

    public void register(Animal animal) {
        animals.add(animal);
    }

    public Collection<Animal> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

}

public abstract class Animal {

    @Autowired
    private Zoo zoo;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        zoo.register(this);
    }

    @Component
    public static class Giraffe extends Animal {
    }

    @Component
    public static class Monkey extends Animal {
    }

    @Component
    public static class Lion extends Animal {
    }

    @Component
    public static class Tiger extends Animal {
    }

}

public class ZooPatron {

    public ZooPatron(Zoo zoo) {
        System.out.println("There are " + zoo.getAnimals().size()
                             + " different animals.");
    }

}

@Component
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private Zoo zoo;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            private static final int ITERATIONS = 10;
            private static final int DELAY = 5;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) {
                    new ZooPatron(zoo);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // nop
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();     
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
There are 0 different animals.
There are 3 different animals.
There are 4 different animals.
There are 4 different animals.
... etc
```

## Explanation of accepted solution

Basically the answer is: no, you cannot guarantee the order of `@PostConstruct` calls without either going "outside" Spring or modifying its behaviour.

The real problem here was *not* that I wanted to sequence the `@PostConstruct` invocations, that was merely a *symptom* of the dependencies being expressed incorrectly.

If the consumers of `Zoo` depend upon him, and `Zoo` in turn depends upon `Animal`s, everything works correctly.  My mistake was that I didn't want `Zoo` to depend upon an explicit list of `Animal` subclasses, and therefore introduced this registration method.  As pointed out in the answers, mixing a self-registration mechanism with dependency injection will never work without unnecessary complexity.

The answer is to declare that `Zoo` is dependent upon a *collection* of `Animal`s, then allow Spring to populate the collection through auto-wiring.

Thus, there is no hard list of collection members, they are discovered by Spring, but the dependencies are correctly expressed and therefore the `@PostConstruct` methods happen in the sequence I want.

Thanks for the excellent answers.

Comment: Ok, i only checked it very fast... but i think Giraffe, monkey, lion and tiget should have a @PostConstuct too.  And why the static?

Comment: Those concrete animals don't need PostConstruct, their abstract parent's PostConstruct method is correctly invoked by Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might instead have the Set of Animals `@Inject`ed into the Zoo.

```
@Component
public class Zoo {

    @Inject
    private Set<Animal> animals = new HashSet<Animal>();

    // ...
}
```

Then Zoo's `@PostConstruct` should only be called once all the Animals are injected.  The only gotcha is that there must be at least one Animal in the system, but it doesn't sound like that should be an issue.

Comment: Yes, this is the best idea, as also suggested by @ptyx.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to ensure @PostConstruct order without introducing dependencies.

I think you're looking for trouble trying to mix injection or self registration. To some extent, @PostConstruct call order should not matter - if it does, it might not be the right tool for the job.

A couple ideas for your example

- try to have an @Autowired on Zoo#animals: no need for self-registration by animals, also the zoo is aware of the animals but not the reverse, which feels cleaner
- keep the register, but let external actors do the registration (someone is putting the animals in the zoo, right? - they're not showing up at the entrance all by themselves)
- if you need to insert new animals at any time, but don't want manual insertion, do a more dynamic accessor on zoo: don't store the list of animals, but use the spring context to get all existing instances of the interface.

I don't think there is a 'right' answer, it all depends on your use case.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head - I can't find a way to make this work without distorting the purpose of PostConstruct.  At the root of the problem is that I don't want anyone to be aware of particular animals (which is probably more to do with my build architecture than anything else); I can't have code changes if I change the set of animals.  Having an animal on the classpath should be sufficient for him to be wired into the system.  However, other people need to know the total set of such animals at runtime.

Comment: If your animals are beans, then use a collection autowired. Spring will automatically put all declared beans in a autowired Map<String,Animal> animals; - you don't need to list them one by one in the Zoo bean.

Comment: Yes, a collection autowired is the best solution.  Once the dependencies are expressed correctly, then the sequence of PostConstruct invocations is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Reframe your problem so that it *doesn't* rely on invocation order.

Comment: Yes.  I see now that the dependencies as expressed in the code are back-to-front; fixing that means that I don't have to rely on invocation order.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, IMO, is to avoid doing too much work during the construction of the object graph (just as in Java, you avoid doing too much work in the constructor), and to avoid calling methods from dependencies when you're not sure they're fully initialized yet.

If you just remove the @PostConstruct annotation from the `Test#init()` method, and simply invoke it from your main method, after the context has been created, you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Perhaps my example code was too simplified; actually my application is a webapp, so I have a XmlWebApplicationContext, courtesy of a DispatcherServlet.  So, I'm not sure I have that opportunity.

Comment: You could still initialize your Test class (or whatever its real name is) in a lazy way (first time one of its method is called, or first time it's accessed through a factory), or using a ServletContextListener.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that in your case there is a dependency between the Zoo object and all your animal types. If you design your Zoo object to reflect this dependency the problem is solved.
For example you could do:

```
<bean id="zoo" class="Zoo">
<property name="animals">
<list>
<ref bean="Monkey" />
<ref bean="Tiger" />
<ref bean="Lion" />
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

instead of using the register method.

Comment: Ah, no - that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid :-) Neither the ZooPatron nor the Zoo want to have a "hard" list of animals. The real world situation is actually that I have a bunch of *games* that are contributed from various Maven artifacts, and a *game registry* in the 'core' of the system. Only the game registry will be visible to the rest of the system, the individual games are not known to the developer who consumes the game registry, but they are known to Spring at compile time when a "distribution" is assembled from the various games and other components.  I'll edit the q to clarify.

Comment: You are right: in the problem domain, the zoo depends upon the animals.  Expressing it any other way leads to problems.  My stupidity was in assuming I had to make an explicit list of animals, when Spring can inject a collection for me.